# Self-dual representation implies that the invariants are trivial iff the coinvariants are trivial.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ be a representation of a group $G$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over an algebraically closed field.

In a paper that I´m reading it states the following:

If the representation $\rho$ is self-dual then the $G$-invariants are trivial if and only if the $G$-coinvariants are trivial.

I would appreciate any reference of this fact.

Answer (score 2):

Any non-zero $G$ equivariant map from the trivial representation into $V$ can be dualized to get a $G$ equivariant map from $V^*$ to the trivial representation, and you can dualize again to get back what you started.

In particular this says that the space of invariants of $V$ is the same as the space of coinvariants of $V^*$, so if one is trivial than so is the other. If $V \cong V^*$ then this gives the result you want.